# css vertical scrolling for the fixed div

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-position

i have a div with lets say

```
height:2000px
```

and

```
width: 30px
```

and i need to fix its position

however when i use

```
position: fixed
```

then although the div is always visible, i cannot scroll vertically to see the "overflowed" content

i found this plugin:
https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

but it works only for the horizontal scrolling.

Any ideas what can i do???

Comment: How could you ever scroll to the bottom of a fixed div? It doesn't mind any scrolling, it is only positioned in relation to the window.

Comment: Do you want `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;` instead?

Comment: check this example (how the header works) from the plugin above:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/

What i need is this functionality with vertical scroll

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with javascript.  If you take a look at the source of the plugin you mentioned, you will see that it stores the offset of the target element and sets its left position based on the horizontal scroll position; which means it is implementing its own "fixed" functionality.

Basically, if the horizontal scroll is at 200, shift the target to the left by 200.  You would do this vertically rather than horizontally.

Every time the window is scrolled (bind to the window.scroll event), check the vertical position, then move the element in the opposite direction (up) by the vertical scroll position, keeping its left where it started.  That will make it appear as if it is fixed.

Look at the plugin's source if you have any questions about how it does this:

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/blob/master/jquery-scrolltofixed.js

**EDIT:** I should have said, overrides the fixed functionality.  Make your target element fixed, then adjust its vertical position according to the vertical scroll position as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try `position: absolute;` Fix will keep the position of the element the same. When using `absolute` "The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element", check w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)